# fetch api not reinstating search values

Tags: javascript, html, fetch, pug

Hello everyone it seems that nobody has been able to walk me through in regards to a fetch issue I am having.

I am building up a library using the google api but here is the catch, if I search for "Harry"(Using Harry for explaining purposes) it does show up some books BUT if I search again letś say "Potter" then both search requests pile up and i just need the first search to flush out and the second search result to show up instead I am filling up the SEARCH BOOKS TEMPLATE and do not have the slightest idea on how to go about getting this fixed

[first search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC1HV.png)

[second search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzwBw.png)

Pug:

```
extends ./index.pug
block contentt
  #categContainer
    h3 Elige a continuación unas de las categorias para poder filtrar tu busqueda adecuadamente
    ul#categories 
      button.btn.btn-autor.btn-outline-info.categories(
        type="button",
        onclick="agregarAutor()"
      ) Autor
      button.btn.btn-libro.btn-outline-info.categories(
        type="button",
        onclick="agregarLibro()"
      ) Libros
      button.btn.btn-revista.btn-outline-info.categories(
        type="button",
        onclick="agregarCategoria()"
      ) Categoria
      button.btn.btn-titulo.btn-outline-info.categories(
        type="button",
        onclick="agregarTitulo()"
      ) titulo
      button.btn.btn-editorial.btn-outline-info.categories(
        type="button",
        onclick="agregarEditorial() "
      ) Casa editora
      button.btn.btn-gratis.btn-outline-info.categories(
        type="button",
        onclick="agregarFree()"
      ) Libros gratuitos
      button.btn.btn-pagas.btn-outline-info.categories(
        type="button",
        onclick="agregarPaid()"
      ) Libros pagos
  div
    label(for="category_type")
    input.input(type="text", name="category_type")
    button.btn.btn-outline-primary.choice(onclick="restartItems()") Elige tu categoria
  #category_reveil
```

JS

```
var acumulado = [];
var input_el = document.querySelector(".input");
valor = input_el;
valor.innerHTML = "";
var autorcito = document.querySelector(".btn-autor");
var librito = document.querySelector(".btn-libro");
var revistica = document.querySelector(".btn-revista");
var titulacho = document.querySelector(".btn-titulo");
var editoriale = document.querySelector(".btn-editorial");
var free = document.querySelector(".btn-gratis");
var paid = document.querySelector(".btn-pagas");
function agregarAutor() {
  acumulado.push("Autor");
  console.log(acumulado);
  autorcito.disabled = true;
}
function agregarLibro() {
  acumulado.push("Libro");
  console.log(acumulado);
  librito.disabled = true;
}
function agregarCategoria() {
  acumulado.push("Categoria");
  console.log(acumulado);
  revistica.disabled = true;
}
function agregarTitulo() {
  acumulado.push("Titulo");
  console.log(acumulado);
  titulacho.disabled = true;
}
function agregarEditorial() {
  acumulado.push("Editorial");
  console.log(acumulado);
  editoriale.disabled = true;
}
function agregarFree() {
  acumulado.push("Gratis");
  console.log(acumulado);
  free.disabled = true;
}
function agregarPaid() {
  acumulado.push("Pagos");
  console.log(acumulado);
  paid.disabled = true;
}
function restartItems() {
  autorcito.disabled = false;
  librito.disabled = false;
  revistica.disabled = false;
  titulacho.disabled = false;
  editoriale.disabled = false;
  free.disabled = false;
  paid.disabled = false;
  acumulado = [];
  console.log(acumulado);
  fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${valor}`)
    .then((data) => {
      return data.json();
    })
    .then((response) => {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
        var item = response.items[i].volumeInfo.title;
        var new_item_list = document.createElement("a");
        var new_item = document.createElement("div").appendChild(new_item_list);
        new_item.classList.add("div_categ_style");
        var item = response.items[i];
        document
          .querySelector("#category_reveil")
          .appendChild(new_item).innerHTML += "<br>" + item.volumeInfo.title;
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: please format your code to be more human-readable :)

Comment: About question/answer [formatting on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), here is a useful page to bookmark ;) -- Other advise, you will get more support if you provide the compiled HTML.

Comment: Guys @Louys it took me a while but I finally ended up uploading the code on github https://github.com/andresafag/BookStore please I do need your help on solving this out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i just need the first search to flush out and the second search result to show up instead I am filling up the SEARCH BOOKS TEMPLATE

No where you empty its content... So for sure it piles up. I also cleaned the logic about element creation a bit. See comments within the code.

```
fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${valor}`)
  .then((data) => {
    return data.json();
  })
  .then((response) => {
    
    // Get #category_reveil
    let category_reveil = document.querySelector("#category_reveil")
        
    // Clear #category_reveil
    category_reveil.innerHTML = ""
    
    // Process the response
    response.items.forEach(item => {
      
      // Create the anchor and its text
      let a = document.createElement("a");
      a.innerText = item.volumeInfo.title;
      
      // Create the div and its class
      let div = document.createElement("div");
      div.classList.add("div_categ_style");
      
      // Append a to div
      div.appendChild(a)
      
      // Append div to #category_reveil
      category_reveil.appendChild(div)
    }
  });
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO VERY MUCH!!! I've been struggling with this a few weeks now and could not figure out how to do it, somehow I thought the problem was about not emptying the input value...crappy logic jaja. Thank you man I appreciate it!!